# Mysterious linebreak will not disappear

Tags: php, mybb

I've been struggling for hours with this problem now.
I'm using the forum software MyBB, and I've recently installed a plugin I'm trying to customize a bit. The purpose is to display recent posts and recent threads, and it does this greatly, but I'm having issues with the design.

**This is how it looks**.
[image: https://prnt.sc/iow26s]

So, as you can see, the bottom three posts work great, and that's because they're displaying **recently created threads**. The top two are displaying **recently created posts**.

To give you more to work with, here is the plugin code that I've been doing all these in: https://pastebin.com/g25QeJ8m.

On line **289** the br's are added, and they seem to show up in both examples.

```
<div class="entry" data-stream="' . $data['stream'] . '">
' . $location .' <br />'. $item . '<br /> <span class="date">' . $date . '</span>
  <br /><br /></div>';
```

And on line **52**, these lines appear to control the **recent posts** lines.

```
$forum    = '<a href="' . $mybb->settings['bburl'] . '/' . get_forum_link($row['fid']) . '" style="color:#fff;">' . $row['name'] . ' </a><br />';
    $thread   = '<a href="' . get_post_link($row['pid'], $row['tid']) . '#pid' . $row['pid'] . ' "style="text-transform:none; font-weight: normal;">' . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . '</a></strong>';
```

I've searched the entire code for additional linebreaks, but I can not for the love of god find anything. Live demo is here: ---

Comment: Open html source code of your page.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Removing any <br> on 289 just removes the space between the posts, not the space between the post title and time.

Comment: I see `</strong>` - but where is `<strong>`?

Comment: @u_mulder I removed half of a strong tag earlier, but it's gone now. Still doesn't change the br.

Comment: Where is `<span>` closed? Please, open your source html and check everything.

Comment: @u_mulder Which span are you talking about? The one on line 289 closes right after $date. 

I've attached the pastebin for the php code, there is nothing manually in the HTML code I can change.

Comment: Here what source code in firefox shows me http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/03/09/0018/0306/1204530/30/56d028a533.jpg Can you explain these red parts?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was on line **109** for anyone wondering. Thanks for the help though!